# Proper way to modify a linked list item in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, parameter-passing

I am working with linked lists in C and trying to understand the correct way of passing a node to a function and modifying that node's value.

Assume for the sake of these examples that I have a single-node list and only care about modifying that first node.

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next
};
```

In main I declare my (single node) list:

```
int main(){ 
    struct node *first;
    first = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first->value = 5;
    first->next  = NULL;
    //someFunctA(first);
    //someFunctB(&first);
};
```

To modify `first->value` in a function, should I use:

```
void someFunctA(struct node *modify){
    modify->value = 10;}
```

or:

```
void someFunctB(struct node **modify){
    struct node *temp = *modify;
    temp->value = 10;}
```

(Or neither of these?)

Both of *seem* to work - after calling either `someFunctA(home)` or `someFunctB(&home)` and I see the expected value in `first->value` in `main()` after calling them (10 in this case).

Are either of these methods correct? Both? If both, what are the tradeoffs between the two?

Also, is it possible to pass `first` with a reference pointer (as in `someFunctB`, right?) and still work on it directly without making a copy? (When I pass with the reference pointer and attempt to access `modify->value`, `*modify->value` or `**modify->value` in the function, I get the error `request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union`.)

Comment: If the function needs to modify the data but doesn't need to work on the list itself, it probably shouldn't take a list node... it should probably just take a pointer to the data, or return the new value to be assigned outside the function.  So how about `void someFuncA(int *val) { *val = 10; }` called as `someFuncA(&first->value);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both of those will work, but you probably want the first version. You're passing a pointer to the node so your function is able to modify the node itself. The second version gives you the ability to modify the pointer (i.e., the variable `first` in `main()`), but if you don't need to do that, there's no reason to use the second option.

As to your question about using `modify`directly in the second function, the correct syntax is `(*modify)->value = 10`.